# aplicar una funcion de clase a un atributo pasando dicho atributo como argumento

Tags: python, clase

Tengo una clase que modifica ligeramente un diccionario para poder llamar a las claves como atributos (también uso el mismo sistema para hacer llamadas a redis)

```
class Propdict(dict):
    def __getattr__(self, key):
        print('self', self, 'key', key)
        return self.get(key)

    def __setattr__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.__setitem__(*args, **kwargs)

    def __delattr__(self, item):
        self.pop(item)

    def di_hola(self, objetive):
        if isinstance(objetive, str):
            print('Hola ',  objetive)
        else:
            print('No voy a saludar a un objeto de tipo', type(objetive))
```

de este modo puedo consultar atributos  como Propdict.nombre, así como setearlos o borrarlos.

La pregunta es ¿como puedo pasar dicho atributo a una función de la misma clase? (si es que se puede)

por ejemplo:

```
saludador = Propdict()
saludador.visitante = 'Antonio'
saludador.visitante.di_hola()
```

El resultado que quiero es "Hola Antonio"

Answer (score 2):

Tal como lo tienes no se puede.

`saludador.visitante` llama a `saludador.__getattr__("visitante")`. En tu caso éste retorna una cadena (`"Antonio"`), por lo que seguidamente tu intento de `saludador.visitante.di_hola()` sería equivalente a `"Antonio".di_hola()`, lo cual fracasa porque el tipo `str` no tiene el método `.di_hola()`.

La única forma en que se me ocurre que podría funcionar, es que tu `__getattr__()` devuelva un objeto que implemente `di_hola()`, lo cual me parece un poco retorcido. Algo así:

```py
class Prop:
  def __init__(self, value):
    self.value = value

  def di_hola(self):
    print('Hola',  self.value)


class Propdict(dict):
    def __getattr__(self, key):
        return self.get(key)

    def __setattr__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.__setitem__(*args, **kwargs)

    def __delattr__(self, item):
        self.pop(item)

saludador = Propdict()
saludador.visitante = Prop('Antonio')
saludador.visitante.di_hola()
```

¿Para qué escenario real necesitas esto? Tiene pinta de que pueda tratarse de un problema XY, en el que preguntas cómo hacer Y, pero en realidad necesitas resolver X.

Comment: Como he comentado tengo algo similar (en realidad identico solo que llama a redis) y quiero implementar metodos que aumenten o disminuyan el elemento despues de devolver su valor, que hagan comprobaciones, que lo borren tras devolverlo, ect
por ejemplo saludador.visitante.del() que devuelva el valor de visitante y lo borre o bien saludador.numvisitante.next() que devuelva el número de visitante actual y lo aumente en uno, sé que puedo hacerlo a la inversa saludador.next('visitante') aunque también me vale saludador.next().visitante

Comment: , el caso es que he usado bastantes diccionarios y las comillas son un dolor de cabeza por eso quiero evitarlas en la medida de lo posible mientras hago replaces masivos

Comment: Igual [Box](https://github.com/cdgriffith/Box) te interesa. Convierte diccionarios (con cualquier nivel de anidamiento, incluso provenientes de json) en objetos con atributos accesibles vía punto. No obstante, una cosa es el acceder a atributos vía punto en vez de corchetes, y otra que esos atributos que accedes tengan a su vez métodos como `di_hola()`, cosa que `Box` tampoco te resuelve, pues los atributos típicamente son cadenas o números, o otros diccionarios.